# Variance of negative binomial given an offset

Tags: negative-binomial-distribution, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, offset

Given observations $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ from the negative binomial distribution, $NB(\mu, \theta)$, and assume that we model the mean with a GAM:

$$\log E(Y_i) = \log \mu_i = \log t_i + f(x_i),$$

where $\log t_i$ is the offset (lets say the exposure given in years). In `mgcv` the negative binomial distribution is parameterized such that $Var(Y_i) = \mu_i + \mu_i^2/\theta$.

Given an observation $Y_i$ with exposure of two years i.e. $t_i = 2$. How should we calculate the variance of this variable? Should $\theta$ also be scaled with the offset $t_i$? If we don't scale it with the offset we get

$$ Var(Y_i | t_i = 2) =  2 \exp(f(x_i)) + \frac{4 \exp(2f(x_i))}{\theta} = 2\bigg (\exp(f(x_i)) + \frac{2 \exp(2f(x_i))}{\theta}\bigg )> 2 Var(Y_i | t_i = 1),$$

meaning that the variance does not scale linearly. If we want the variance to scale linearly, as is the case for the Poisson model, we have to multiply $\theta$ by $t_i$ and we get:

$$ Var(Y_i | t_i = 2) = 2 Var(Y_i | t_i = 1)$$

`mgcv` does not scale $\theta$ with $t_i$, but doesn't it make sense that the variance should scale linearly in the offset?